# Excel fetch multiple value in a table

Tags: excel-formula

I have an excel table that looks like this:

```
                classe A    classe B    classe C    classe D
0   ans/jaar    € 1,688.58  € 1,758.94  € 1,783.81  € 1,924.17
1   ans/jaar    € 1,693.67  € 1,769.02  € 1,783.81  € 1,936.90
2   ans/jaar    € 1,698.72  € 1,779.13  € 1,824.04  € 1,949.41
```

So for example when I enter `1`in a cell I want to display the result of (2000 - 1693,67)

is this possible in excel?

I do a lookup but I only get the value in classe d

`1936.90 1936.90 1936.90 1936.90`

I want this:

`1693.67 1769.02 1783.81 1936.90`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in the first cell:

```
= INDEX($C:$F,MATCH($H$3,$A:$A,0),COLUMN(A:A))
```

Then copy across.

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for your response but I dont want the max and min I want all the values of classe A - B - C - D and suctract for example 2000 with these values

Comment: please edit your original post to indicate how you want to show those.